# PEM_read_PrivateKey failed

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, mac-osx, ssh-keys

I'm trying to use ssh to log in to AWS from OSX Mavericks and having a hell of a time. I enter:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/filename.pem
ec2-user@ec2-xx-x-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -v
```

And I get this, as well as a keychain popup that asks for a password, even though there is none to give...

```
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Saving password to keychain failed.
```

I launched a new instance on AWS and generated a new key pair. When I left the .pem file unprotected, the OSX keychain popup didn't appear, but I was unable to access AWS because the file was unprotected:

> Permissions 0644 for '/Users/cvn/.ssh/chris-test.pem' are too open.
>
> It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by
>
> others.  This private key will be ignored. bad permissions: ignore
>
> key: /Users/cvn/.ssh/chris-test.pem  Permission denied (publickey).

So I ran

```
chmod 400 chris-test.pem
```

and the Keychain returned asking for a password that I do not have...

Comment: Sounds like the format of your pem file is wrong. Check that you've got all of the required content. Running SSH with debug switches might give a clue (`-d -d-d`)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? same issue...

Answer (score 6):

In my case private key was in openssh format (line `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` in key file to check), but *client* ssh works only with rsa format (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` line). I'd just converted one to another and it works. See how to convert Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817907/11870451).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're really using private key (not a public one, not something else) and double-check its content.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/314874)

Comment: @DaveM now it's better?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the line `IdentitiesOnly=yes` from my `~/.ssh/config` file solved the issue.